# listItems not working when base element is input in igEditor

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui

i am adding textfields dynamically as

```
var input = $('<input class="EditorFields" id="textfield"/>');
$(input).igEditor({
                width: 140,
                required:true
            });
```

this is working fine.
But when i am trying to add listItems property then its not working.

```
$(input).igEditor({
                width: 140,
                required:true,
                listItems : ["red","blue","yellow"]
            });
```

i do not want to change the base element to select.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first - the [Ignite UI jQuery API docs](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.1/ui.igtexteditor#options) state that the button option defaults to none - if you want to have a drop-down add this:

```
button : "dropdown",
```

Why this still won't work? Dynamically adding dynamic controls is tricky sometimes if you don't know them in great detail. Same for jQuery, it's a common thing people miss - jQuery creates items in a **document fragment** so you need to be careful how you append them to the DOM.

When you provide an INPUT element and request a complex editor, the control's additional items (buttons, drop-down, validation messages, etc.) are built around that input and the whole thing wrapped in a container SPAN. Because you refer to the input and it works the first time I assume you attach it directly. Basically when you create a **complex editor** and only afterwards attach to eh DOM using the same input reference you are leaving all the extra markup stuck in the document fragment.

I can think of about 3 ways to get this to work, you pick what suits best yopur needs:

**1)** Append item first so the Editor can properly initialize in the DOM afterwards:

```
var input = $('<input class="EditorFields" id="textfield"/>').appendTo("body");
```

**2)** Povide the container, instead the input if possible:

```
var input1 = $('<span class="EditorFields" id="textfield1"/>');
```

**3)** Select the parent when you know you have one and append it instead:

```
 $(input2).igEditor({
        width: 140,
        required: true,
        listItems: ["red2", "blue2", "yellow2"],
        button: "dropdown"
    }).parent().appendTo("body");
```

Here's a JSFiddle with all of those: http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/ZRqb2/

Comment: i was having same issue with datepicker also but after appending to DOM first solved the issue.Thanks